# Visa refusal to Australia due to overstaying family members

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, australia

I want to know how I can reapply for an Australian visitor's visa that was earlier refused because I have family members who had stayed beyond their stay period on their own visitors visa in 2011.

These family members are now Australian citizens and Permanent Residents. They had applied for a bridging visa while within their stay period and were granted it in a legal way.

But every time I apply, the Australian embassy in my country still refuse saying my family did not honor their stay period. What can I do to be able to get a visa?

Comment: You have family members that have entered Australia on visitor visas and then applied to stay permanently. At a guess, I'd say the Australians think you will try the same thing. You are going to have to be very persuasive to convince them otherwise if you do intend to leave, or you're going to have to apply for the long stay visa you really want. If you post the refusal letters (with personal details blanked out) we could be more certain.

Comment: @Willow “Every time I apply...” - how many times?

Comment: In this case having a family member in Australia is a negative fact. Which kind of visa you applied? Do you have good job, family or other objective facts that you will return to your home country?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.